# Chartboost Move startWithAppId from applicationDidBecomeActive to "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

Tags: chartboost

```
[Chartboost startWithAppId:@"53fadf0fc26ee44b06c83ecf" appSignature:@"0f826389808ef0f260256a1ec632f6bedce8c4d0" delegate:self];
```

I've moved it from applicationDidBecomeActive to "application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions".

But I'm afraid they must doing some install checking things in startWithAppId. So does it matter if I move it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you move it here, yes. The more important is to be sure it's called just one time.

But I recommend you to do exactly what Chartboost ask us to do in their tutos